# Is it possible to install Swift Playgrounds in iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios-appstore, xcode, xcode-simulator

My iPad is not capable of running Swift Playgrounds. I am wondering if I installed Xcode on my Mac and used the iOS Simulator, would it be possible to access the iOS App Store and install Swift Playgrounds on that so I could take a look at the app?

I don't need to extensively use the app, I just want to have a look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to access the App Store from an Xcode simulator.  Apple doesn't install the App Store on the simulator and there's no way to add the app.

You can only access [Swift Playgrounds](https://www.apple.com/swift/playgrounds/) from a real iPad running iOS 10 or later.

Comment: a real iPad with 64bit architecture that is